# Как ускорить перемещение символа в консоли по нажатию клавиш?

Tags: c++

Программа перемещает букву H, но делает это медленно.
Как можно написать по-другому?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool flag;
    char c;
    int x,y;
    flag = true;
    cout << "H";
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    system("color 6");
    while ((flag) && (c = getch()))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 72:
            {
                //Вверх
                system("cls");
                //clrscr(); 
                y--;
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                    cout << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                    cout << " ";
                cout << "H";

            }
            break;
        case 75:
            {
                //Влево
                system("cls");
                x--;
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                    cout << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                    cout << " ";
                cout << "H";
            }

            break;
        case 77:
            {
                //Вправо
                system("cls");
                x++;
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                    cout << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                    cout << " ";
                cout << "H";
            }
            break;
        case 80:
            {
                //Вниз
                system("cls");
                y++;
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                    cout << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                    cout << " ";
                cout << "H";
            }
            break;
        case 27:
            flag = false;
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }
    }

    //  getch();
    //  getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Круассан окно. К чему это я. Ах да, рекомендую переформулировать заголовок вопроса более осмысленно. Будет удобнее и экспертам, и новичкам, у которых, возможно, возникнет та же проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, как вы сами можете наблюдать, в вашей конструкции `switch` идет четырехкратное повторение одного и того же кода. Это не совсем правильно, и, скорее всего, именно это и тормозит работу программы. Лично у меня, в компиляторе Dev-C++ все работает нормально.

Попробуйте так:

```
bool flag;
char c;
int x,y;
flag = true;
cout << "H";
x = 0;
y = 0;
system("color 6");
while ((flag) && (c = getch()))
{

    switch (c)
    {
    case 72:
            y--;
            break;
    case 75:
            x--;
            break;
    case 77:
           x++;
           break;
    case 80:
            y++;
            break;
    case 27:
        flag = false;
        break;
    default: 
        break;
    }

    /////////// Вынесли повторяющийся блок кода ////////////
    system("cls");  
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                cout << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                cout << " ";
                cout << "H"; 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Всё равно тормозит. Сделал с помощью SetConsoleCursorPosition и стало лучше

Comment: 72.. 75.. 77.. 80.. Что за magic numbers? Используйте константы.

Comment: @Asen, это не вам лично. А вообще всем в данном топике.

Comment: @Nofate, наверняка вы знаете, что это коды клавиш стрелок. Константы здесь ни в чем не выигрывают. Их использование эквивалентно данному использованию цифр-кодов.

Comment: Вот не поверите, ни сном ни духом не ведаю ) 

Мы со Стивом Макконнеллом всегда ожидаем увидеть в коде что-то в духе VK_UP, VK_DOWN.

>  Константы здесь ни в чем не выигрывают

Константы всегда выигрывают тем, что они позволяют понять, что значит конкретное значение.

Comment: @Deeech, Проблема в system("cls") в цикле. Очищайте экран один раз в начале.

В цикле Вам надо просто делать SetConsoleCursorPosition() в oldPos, выводить пробел, затем SetConsoleCursorPosition() в newPos и рисовать свой символ.

Ну, Вы скорректируйте соответственно свой код с gotoxy(x,y).

Просто летать будет.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите избежать многочисленных итераций в циклах при каждой перерисовке буквы, можно перемещать курсор в нужную координату и там рисовать букву. Правда нужно получать хэндл консольного окошка. Это реализовано в функции gotoxy(). Такая функция есть встроенная в Borland. Это что-то вроде ее аналога для MSVC.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 using namespace std;

void gotoxy(short x, short y)
{
 HANDLE StdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 COORD  coord  = {x, y};
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(StdOut, coord);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 bool flag = true;
 char c;
 int x = 0, y = 0;
 system("color 6");
 cout << "H";
 while ((flag) && (c = getch()))
 {
  switch(c)
        {
         case 72:
                {
                 //Вверх
                 y--;
                 break;
                }
         case 75:
                {
                 //Влево
                 x--;
                 break;
                }
         case 77:
                {
                 //Вправо
                 x++;
                 break;
                }
         case 80:
                {
                 //Вниз
                 y++;
                 break;
                }
         case 27:
                {
                 flag = false;
                 break;
                }
         default: break;
       }
  system("cls");
  gotoxy(x, y);
  cout << "H";
 }
 return 0;
}
```